# 100% width Issue in Chrome

Tags: css, layout

I'm trying to create liquid layout, so that the left side of the site expands based on the screen size, while the right side stays a fixed width. This works fine in IE, but in Chrome the left side is only expanding the length of the content within, not the full length of the space.

```
#bbContent{width:100%; min-width:829px;}
#leftActivity
{
float:left;
margin-right:334px;
min-width:421px;
margin-top:18px;
padding-left:14px;
padding-right:60px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#rightActivity
{
float:right;
width:320px;
margin:18px 14px 0 -334px;
}
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? Could you setup of fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Try what happens when you set a relative width to `#leftActivity`, like `min-width: 421px; width: 50%; max-width: 900px;`

Comment: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyomu/KnVrA/) of what I think you have filled with dummy text. Seems to work in FF (I don't have chrome on this computer). But note this is guesswork, and and example from you would be much appreciated as PeeHaa said.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/techsocialite/hvZ6E/ @Kyomu If you make the dummy text in the left smaller, like one word, the div no long expands, as in the green background isn't expanding, only if there is text to fill it up.

Comment: @PeeHaa jsfiddle.net/techsocialite/hvZ6E There's a lot of code going on, so hopefully I included what is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the solution by adding a wrapper around the left side, and removing the float from #leftActivity. Adding a negative margin on the wrapper, and removing the negative margin from the right side.

```
#leftWrap{float:left; width:100%; min-width:421px; margin-right:-334px;}
#leftActivity
{
margin-right:334px;
margin-top:18px;
padding-left:14px;
padding-right:60px;
overflow:hidden;
}
#rightActivity
{
float:left;
width:320px;
margin:18px 14px 0 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/KnVrA/1/

it makes sense for leftActivity not to expand since it is floating, if the content is not that long then it would not expand

Edit: Used Kyomu's fiddle and took out some stuff and rearranged some stuff

Update: using percent based http://jsfiddle.net/KnVrA/2/

you can add wrappers inside of the left to create padding on the right side

Comment: The problem with that, is there are other divs within leftActivity. So even if I removed that div, there are other divs, and thus the right content moves below it without the float.

Comment: @Audrey please create a fiddle to demonstrate the worst case scenario or perhaps you need to make the left and right width % based. If you do percent based, they will both expand accordingly (add min-width if needed)

Comment: I want the right side to be a fixed width, so percent won't work there.